# Clean up memory after P/Invoke a C++ function

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, ipc

My application is a C# program that uses C ++ functions over P/Invoke. 
Before calling a C ++ function the library is loaded:

```
IntPtr hLib = LoadLibrary("CPPFunctions.DLL");
```

and after the C++ function returned it's results over a callback to my C# Application the library gets cleaned up:

```
FreeLibrary(hLib);
```

A library that is used within C++ is storing memory, but never releases it. This is because the library is a simulation model whose process is usually terminated after a run.

This means that I will need more and more memory if the function is called repeatedly.

Is there a way to completely free the memory allocated by C++?

Comment: `FreeLibrary` would just free the memory allocated for the dll image as the name implies. Without a pointer to the resource allocated during the function call, there is no way to clean that up.

Comment: Sounds like you would need to spin up and communicate with an independent process relying on its termination to cause the OS to clean up.

Comment: "...whose process is usually terminated after a run.", are you saying your library creates a separate process when you use it? If it terminates with separate process you would not have a memory leak since the process and it's resources are terminated/released.

Comment: @AlexK. Thanks for advice. Does this following the same?https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3d072d04-c2e8-4dd6-ac2c-e9e20adb0fb4/c-load-dll-in-separate-domain-and-use-its-methods?forum=csharpgeneral

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't something that you can do from the outside. The library must provide facilities to enable this. Either the library has been badly designed and leaks unavoidably, or you are failing to call the cleanup functions that it provides.

Either way, there is no magic pinvoke function that can solve this problem. The way forward will be found by studying the library and its documentation. You may need to get in touch with its developer.